# scikit: cross validation with metric='precomputed' and Nearest Neighbors

Tags: classification, cross-validation, python, k-nearest-neighbour

My goal is to classify samples based on their dynamic time warping distances with k-nearest-neighbor classification.

Therefore I compute a `nxn` matrix, where `n` is the total number of samples. This matrix contains the distance from each sample to each sample.

The `precomputed` metric should be the right choice for the task since I do not want the `KNeighborsClassifier` to actually compute distances between rows, it should rather just take the distances out of the matrix.

I try to split this matrix in training and test data using k-fold-validation.

However, I get unrealistic poor classification results, and I do not really understand how the `precomputed` metric is supposed to be used when splitting data into training data and test data. What is wrong with the following code? Maybe the index splicing using `iloc`?

```
    X = compute_full_distance_matrix(input_data) # store distances in a pandas data frame
    Y = get_target_labels() # the target labels for each row

    kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
    kf.get_n_splits(X)

    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

        X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index, train_index], X.iloc[test_index, train_index]
        Y_train, Y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]

        model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='precomputed')
        model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
        predictions = model.predict(X_test)

        print(classification_report(Y_test,predictions))
```

Comment: Try to split your data first into test and train data and then compute the full distance matrix X which you feed into the KNeighbours function. I do not see any other issue

Comment: I am not sure how this is different to throwing out columns and rows during the folds. It would actually lead to multiple computations of the same distances?

Comment: Yes, it would. I only wonder whether it is different because you explicitly named the .iloc splitting as a potential source of error. Other than that it is simply possible that KNeighbors with 3 neighbours is not working fine. Try other parameters and other classifiers. Further you would want to optimize your parameter using crossvalidation and then evaluate with another set.

Comment: I know from a similar matlab implementation that at least 50% accuracy can be achieved by this method with the given training samples

Comment: 1) Did you compare whether the distance matrix is exactly the same as in matlab, 2) presumably the test train split is random and therefore not the same as in matlab --> not the same accuracy as a result

Comment: Although the split is random, it should be pretty consistent when the result is averaged over multiple folds. Yes the matrix is the same, except for a small constant factor